# Linear map and skalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Let assume linear map $L: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$, defined as $Lu:=\langle v,u\rangle v$

where $u\in \mathbb{C}^3$ and $v\in \mathbb{C}^3$ is non-zero chosen vector with its norm $||v|| = 1$. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ stands for standard scalar multiplication (linear in right and antilinear in left argument) on $C^3$.

I would like to calculate for example $L((1,0,0))$, which expands to $\langle v, (1,0,0)\rangle v$ where I get lost.

---

*Note: I am not very familiar with the english's math terminology, so if there's something that doesn't make sense, please comment.*

Comment: If $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then $\langle v,(1,0,0)\rangle = v_1$, so $L((1,0,0)) = v_1 v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I not mistake. Standard scalar product means that 
$$
\langle v,u\rangle = \bar v_1 u_1 + \bar v_2 u_2 + \bar v_3 u_3.
$$
From here $L((1,0,0)) = \bar v_1 v$.

Comment: Does $v_1v$ equal to $(v_1v_1,v_1v_2,v_1v_3)$ then?

Comment: @tsusanka yes, it is vector $v$   multiplied by scalar $v_1$.

Comment: One more question, just to clarify the $Lu$ actually mean $L(u)$ right?

Comment: @tsusanka yes, for linear operator it is usual notation $Lu$

Comment: Last thing: if the scalar multiplication is defined as 'linear in right and antilinear in left argument' shouldn't it be $$
\langle v,u\rangle = \bar v_1 u_1 + \bar v_2 u_2 + \bar v_3 u_3.
$$ instead?

Comment: @tsusanka well, we should look at definition. Where have you got it ?

Comment: that's the problem I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23762/discussion-between-nikita-evseev-and-tsusanka).